# Python Pysnmp Loop always returns must be string type error, even though the variable is a string

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am new to python, so maybe a similar question has been asked and I didn't understand the answer as it pertains to my situation, and sorry if this is a dumb question.

I am passing this snmp function, either get or bulk, a list of ip addresses to loop through and then print the MIB information i'm requesting.

I've attempted to do this so many ways; different loops, list comprehension, using .join and .split to make them a comma separated string, using enumerate and looping over the indexes, using netaddr variables, etc. and usually end up with some sort of type error. I'm trying to pass each ip address as a string to the function, which is asking for a string. If I try to loop over the list directly with a 'for a in a:' loop, I end up with a similar error.

When I print the type for each string, it says it is a string. Why would this not work and what is the recommended method?

in this specific situation i'm getting the following errors:

if snmp bulk:

TYPEError: int () argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ObjectType'

if snmp get:

TYPEError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Code and results listed below:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

from nmapPoller import a



def snmpquery(hostip):

    snmp_iter = bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),

                        CommunityData('public'),

                        UdpTransportTarget((hostip, 161)),

                        ContextData(),
                        1,
                        255,

                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB','ifOperStatus')),

                        lexicographicMode=True)

    for errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds in snmp_iter:

        # Check for errors and print out results

        if errorIndication:

            print(errorIndication)

        elif errorStatus:

            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),

                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))

        else:

            for varBind in varBinds:

                print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))

print(a)
result: ['10.200.100.1', '10.200.100.8']
print(type(a))
result: <class 'list'>
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    host = a[i]
    str(host) this can be excluded I believe
    print(host)
    result: 10.200.100.1
    print(type(host))
    result: <class 'str'>
    #snmpquery(host) <-- Error results from running function
```

User9876 fixed my issue by adding maxrepetitions, added to above.

Answer (score 2):

According to [these docs](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/bulkcmd.html), the function you're calling is defined as:

> `pysnmp.hlapi.bulkCmd(snmpEngine, authData, transportTarget, contextData, nonRepeaters, maxRepetitions, *varBinds, **options)`
>
> maxRepetitions (int)

But for the `maxRepetitions` parameter, you're passing an `ObjectType()` instead of an int.  I think the `ObjectType()` should be one of the `*varBinds`, I think you missed the `maxRepetitions` parameter.

In your code:

```
    snmp_iter = bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                        CommunityData('public'),
                        UdpTransportTarget((hostip, 161)),
                        ContextData(),
                        1,
```

I think you're missing the `maxRepetitions` parameter that should go here...

```
                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB','ifOperStatus')),
                        lexicographicMode=True)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, adding maxrepetitions fixed my issue, resulting relevant code is above.